# How to fix cycles render on mac m1 chip? It freezes blender every time after recent update

Tags: cycles-render-engine

How to fix cycles render on mac m1 chip? It freezes blender every time after recent update.

here is my current version and system

MacBook Air, M1, 2020
Apple M1, memory 16GB
running with Ventura 13.2.1

Blender
3.5.0
Date: 2023-03-29 02:56
Hash: 1be25cfff18b
Branch: blender-v3.5-release
Blender is free software
Licensed under the GNU General Public License

Is there a way to sumbit a bug?

Comment: https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Process/Bug_Reports

Comment: In Blender, Help > Report a Bug menu.